# Why can't I see my updates I made with truffle test in ganache?

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

making my first steps in blockchain technique I picked the most simple example

**SimpleStorage**

I'm using truffle and ganache. I coded the contract simple_storage.sol:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

a Test simple_storage.js:

```
const SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("SimpleStorage");

contract("SimpleStorage", accounts => {
  it("should store 17 into SimpleStorage", async () => {
    const simpleStorageInstance = await SimpleStorage.deployed();
    
    
    // set simpleStorage
    await simpleStorageInstance.set(17, { from: accounts[0] });

    // Get stored value
    const storedData = await simpleStorageInstance.get();

    assert.equal(storedData, 17, "The value 17 was not stored.");
    
  });
});
```

and a Test simple_storage.sol:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/SimpleStorage.sol";

contract TestSimpleStorage {

  function testItStoresAValue() public {
    SimpleStorage simpleStorage = SimpleStorage(DeployedAddresses.SimpleStorage());

    simpleStorage.set(18);
   
    uint l = simpleStorage.get();
    Assert.equal(l, 18, "Abweichung soll nicht sein");
    
    }
}
```

Both Tests are working fine, but contract in ganache ui always shows storedData=0.

A complete source and Test documentation can be found here:

https://github.com/pstrotmann/SimpleStorage

What is the coding necessary to make storedData persistent on ganache blockchain?

Peter
Dortmund, Germany

issue posted:

https://github.com/trufflesuite/trufflesuite.com/issues/1151

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime truffle staff sent me a mail that the observed behavior is due to a rollback at the end of the test suite. That behaviour therefore is a desired feature.
In my opinion that behavior should not be the default behavior of a successful transaction as it is in contrast to the ACID paradigm of Transactions where the D means durability. I think the user at least should have the choice of rollback or not.

Comments welcome